# Change added treenode backcolor to red

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

Seems a fairly simple request but i have not found a solution.
I've programatically added a root node to an asp.net treeview control. I want to change that node and only that node back color to red.

C# asp.net code please anyone? My code to add the node is below.
thanks,

Damo

```
TreeNode onjParent = new TreeNode(ItemShouldExist, ItemShouldExist);                             
onjParent.PopulateOnDemand = true;
TreeViewAddItems.Nodes.Add(onjParent);
onjParent.Checked = true;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This adds 10 nodes to a Treeview, and only node 4 has red background.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i == 4)
            this.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode() { Text = "<span style='background-color:red'>Node_" + i + "</span>", Value = i.ToString() });
        else
            this.TreeView1.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode() { Text = "Node_" + i, Value = i.ToString() });
    }
}
```

Edit: Changed font color to background.
Good luck!

Comment: Worked well for me was also able to change text color